# How to apply a transformation on all values when deserializing Json with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I want to parse a JSON document with [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and apply some transformation on all nodes. For example, let's say that I want all values to be in uppercase after deserialization.

The actual use case is a bit more complex:

- transformation is more complex, the transformer class need to be injected with some configuration, I'd like it to be a configureable instance
- transformation has to happen on all properties, I'd like to be able to not add an annotation on each property of each class deserialized.

There are enough configuration options / hooks in Jackson, so I'm fairly sure that this is possible, I just can't find my way around.

The test below shows what I'm trying to achieve:

```
public class JsonValueFilterTest {

    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Before
    public void setupObjectMapper() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // TODO: configure mapper to upper case all values
    }

    @Test
    public void printJson() throws IOException {
        Entity myEntity = new Entity("myName");
        mapper.writeValue(System.out, myEntity); // prints: {"name":"myName"}
    }

    @Test
    public void valuesAreUpperCasedWhenLoaded() throws IOException {
        Entity myEntity = mapper.readValue("{\"name\":\"myName\"}", Entity.class);
        assertThat(myEntity.getName()).isEqualTo("MYNAME"); // fails
    }

    public static class Entity {
        private final String name;

        @JsonCreator
        public Entity(@JsonProperty("name") String name) { this.name = name; }

        public String getName() { return name; }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return "name='" + name + "'"; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final solution (thanks to Alban):

1. configure the ObjectMapper with a custom JsonNodeFactory which transforms all text nodes
2. deserialize json to `JsonNode` (this will apply transformation)
3. convert the `JsonNode` to my custom class

   public class JsonValueFilterTest {

   ```
   private ObjectMapper mapper;

   @Before
   public void setupObjectMapper() {
       mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       mapper.setNodeFactory(new JsonNodeFactory() {
           @Override
           public TextNode textNode(String text) {
               return super.textNode(text.toUpperCase());
           }
       });
   }

   @Test
   public void printJson() throws IOException {
       Entity myEntity = new Entity("myName");
       mapper.writeValue(System.out, myEntity); // prints: {"name":"myName"}
   }

   @Test
   public void valuesAreUpperCasedWhenLoaded() throws IOException {
       JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree("{\"name\":\"myName\"}");
       Entity myEntity = mapper.treeToValue(jsonNode, Entity.class);
       assertThat(myEntity.getName()).isEqualTo("MYNAME");
   }

   public static class Entity {
       private final String name;

       @JsonCreator
       public Entity(@JsonProperty("name") String name) { this.name = name; }

       public String getName() { return name; }

       @Override
       public String toString() { return "name='" + name + "'"; }
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 6):

You can use converter for that simple case to not implement custom deserializer. I don't know why, but It's not working on the creator constructors, though. So you will have to use non-final fields.

```
public class JsonValueFilterTest {

    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setupObjectMapper() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Test
    public void printJson() throws IOException {
        Entity myEntity = new Entity("myName");
        mapper.writeValue(System.out, myEntity); // prints: {"name":"myName"}
    }

    @Test
    public void valuesAreUpperCasedWhenLoaded() throws IOException {
        Entity myEntity = mapper.readValue("{\"name\":\"myName\"}", Entity.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(myEntity.getName(), "MYNAME"); // fails
    }

    public static class UpCaseConverter extends StdConverter<String, String> {
        public String convert(String value) {
            return value==null ? null : value.toUpperCase();
        }
    }

    public static class Entity {

        private String name;

        public Entity() {}

        public Entity(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @JsonDeserialize(converter = UpCaseConverter.class)
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "name='" + name + "'";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My use case is actually a bit more complex than that. I'll update the question.